# Disable logging to IntelliJ console and use log file instead

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been able to successfully send logs to file using the "Save console output to file:" option in the Logs tab of the Run Configuration, but I'm not sure how to disable logging to the IntelliJ console (so that fewer resources are used). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to disable console logging via the IDE settings.

To reduce the logging impact of the performance you can reduce the console buffer: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Console | Override console cycle buffer size.

Another option would be to use some logging framework in your app (slf4j) and redirect the output to a file via the logging configuration inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

If in Ubuntu, you can redirect stdout and stderr to a file and launch this command as a background process. Note: Both are required to fully mute console output.
Example:
/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh 1>pycharm_stdout.log 2> pycharm_stderr.log &